# Display hex color created by sass

Tags: colors, sass

I have a simple page here:

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/color/

The center blocks color is saved as a variable in sass

The color of the blocks either side are created with sass's lighten and darken.

Is it possible to display the actual hex number of these lighter and darker colors that sass has created.

The color's hex are displayed in the output css but I'd like to be able to do it dynamically and display the hex color in the block.

I have the colors in scss file

```
    $base-blue: #267EC8;

    // Blue

    .at-blue{
        background-color: $base-blue;
    }

    .at-blue-lighter{
        background-color: lighten($base-blue, 20%);
    }

    .at-blue-light{
        background-color: lighten($base-blue, 10%);
    }

    .at-blue-dark{
        background-color: darken($base-blue, 10%);  
    }

    .at-blue-darker{
        background-color: darken($base-blue, 20%);  
    }
```

Then I'm using the class name in the html

```
    <div class="my_Box at-blue-lighter" >.at-blue-lighter<span></span></div>
    <div class="my_Box at-blue-light" >.at-blue-light<span></span></div>
    <div class="my_Box at-blue" >.at-blue <span></span></div>
    <div class="my_Box at-blue-dark" >.at-blue-dark<span></span></div>
    <div class="my_Box at-blue-darker" >.at-blue-darker<span></span></div>
```

And styling the box in separate scss file

```
    .my_Box{
        text-align: center;
        height: 120px;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 30px 0 0;
        width: 120px;

        span{
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `content` to show it : http://jsfiddle.net/A9rML/

```sass
$color : rgb(38, 126, 200);

div{
    background-color: $color;
    &:after{

        content: "#{$color}";
        font-size: 42px;
        color: white;
    }
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: JAre, this looks perfect but I'm dynamically creating the color on a separate scss file and I can't see how I would do this. I have updated my question with further code.

Comment: @ttmt you can setup `.at-blue-lighter{font size bg-color, text color and so on}` and in the file with colors `.at-blue-lighter:after{content: "#{$some-color}";}`  Then `after` will inherit style like font size and color from the `.at-blue-lighter`